# Не выходит выстроить объекты

Tags: html, css, flexbox

Я новичок в вебе, возникла такая проблема.
Нужно чтобы картинка была справа, а все остальные элементы слева. Чтобы все было на одном уровне по вертикали, но выходит только так [image: введите сюда описание изображения]
помогите пожалуйста исправить проблему.

```css
.second-part {
  height: 4.67%;
  background-color: white;
  padding: 20px 30px;
  border: 15px dolid black;
  font-weight: 100;
}

.subtitle-for-second-part {
  display: flex;
}

.subtitle-for-second-part h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.describe-for-second-subtitle {
  display: flex;
}

.describe-for-second-subtitle p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.with-button-second-part {
  display: flex;
}

.button-second-part {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: white;
}

.with-phone-picture {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: flex-end;
}
```

```html
<div class="second-part">
  <div class="subtitle-for-second-part">
    <h2>this is bouncy</h2>
  </div>
  <div class="describe-for-second-subtitle">
    <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui <br> blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos <br> dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non <br> provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia
      deserunt mollitia <br> animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum <br> facilis est et expedita distinctio. </p>
  </div>
  <div class="with-button-second-part">
    <button class="button-second-part">Read more</button>
  </div>
  <div class="with-phone-picture">
    <img src="res/images/phone-for-second-part.png" alt="phone">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```css
.second-part {
  padding: 20px 30px;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

.subtitle-for-second-part h2 {
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.describe-for-second-subtitle p {
  font-size: 12px;
}

.button-second-part {
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 35px;
  background-color: white;
}

.with-phone-picture {
  max-width: 250px;
}

img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

```html
<div class="second-part">
  <div class="column"> <!-- Добавил -->
    <div class="subtitle-for-second-part">
      <h2>this is bouncy</h2>
    </div>
    <div class="describe-for-second-subtitle">
      <p>At vero eos et accusamus et iusto odio dignissimos ducimus qui <br> blanditiis praesentium voluptatum deleniti atque corrupti quos <br> dolores et quas molestias excepturi sint occaecati cupiditate non <br> provident, similique sunt in culpa qui officia
        deserunt mollitia <br> animi, id est laborum et dolorum fuga. Et harum quidem rerum <br> facilis est et expedita distinctio. </p>
    </div>
    <div class="with-button-second-part">
      <button class="button-second-part">Read more</button>
    </div>
  </div>
  
  <div class="column"> <!-- Добавил -->
    <div class="with-phone-picture">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/200" alt="phone">
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Полезный, хороший ответ. Но, на мой взгляд, - раз у человека проблемы с решением элементарной задачи, то ему, и вероятно другим очень нужны разъяснения

Comment: разъяснения как раз не нужны, все понятно.

Comment: @Ram Ce  в этом случае, почему сами не справились? Дали бы самоответ. Глядишь репой бы запаслись за вопрос и ответ :)

Comment: затупил, не сразу понял что к чему